# How can I "transpose" the data in this way with R studio?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, transpose

Hi I have a dataframe similar to the one in the photo (left one) and I'm trying to obtain the format on the right one. How can I do it?

[example dataset and what I would like to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Zth.png)

I know that is a stupid question, but I'm missing something..

How can I obtain that result?
thank you very much!

I tried those one

long_data <- melt(data,id=c("Test"))

data.long <- data %>% pivot_longer(-Test, names_to = "variables", values_to = "value")

I also tried just

data_long=t(data)

Comment: This depends on what you intend to to. To get the provided format in the image you have two possibilites. One is to summarise by sum or mean etc. the other is to keep lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Test) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test, values_from = value) 

 name  Pre       Post     
  <chr> <list>    <list>   
1 Q1    <dbl [4]> <dbl [4]>
2 Q2    <dbl [4]> <dbl [4]>
3 Q3    <dbl [4]> <dbl [4]>
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Test) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest()

name    Pre  Post
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Q1        2     3
 2 Q1        2     2
 3 Q1        1     3
 4 Q1        3     2
 5 Q2        3     2
 6 Q2        3     3
 7 Q2        5     4
 8 Q2        4     2
 9 Q3        4     3
10 Q3        2     4
11 Q3        2     5
12 Q3        3     3
```

OR

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Test) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Test, values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  summarize(mean_pre = mean(Pre), mean_post = mean(Post), .by=name)

  name  mean_pre mean_post
  <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Q1        2         2.5 
2 Q2        3.75      2.75
3 Q3        2.75      3.75
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Test = c("Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Pre", "Post", "Post", 
"Post", "Post"), Q1 = c(2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2), Q2 = c(3, 3, 
5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2), Q3 = c(4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
  reframe(across(starts_with("Q"), mean), .by = Test) %>% 
  data.table::transpose(make.names = 'Test', keep.names = "Name")
```

-output

```
  Name  Pre Post
1   Q1 2.00 2.50
2   Q2 3.75 2.75
3   Q3 2.75 3.75
```